# A module in drupal which lets me have data in tree like structure

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-themes

I am searching for a theme or module in drupal which lets me present my web page in the form given in the image below. The boxes have some content. Is there any theme/module which lets me do this or do i have to write one myself from scratch?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a module to do it, but it should be easy to modify your favourite theme (using a subtheme so you don't miss out on updates) to do this.

You can put an alternating class on the nodes being output in template.php. The rest you should be able to do with CSS.

James